# Login en maquina virtual Fedora CoreOs Virtual Box

Tags: login, ssh, virtualbox, fedora

Estoy empezando a aprender sobre Fedora y estoy bloqueado con el inicio.

**CONTEXTO**

Quiero levantar un Fedora CoreOs para correr docker. Como tengo mac, me valgo de VirtualBox.

Leyendo la documentación de fedoraproject.org lo que hice fue descargar el .ova de Fedora CoreOs 37 desde acá https://fedoraproject.org/es/coreos/download/?stream=stable

Lo importé en VirtualBox y antes de iniciarlo, creé el ignition file siguiendo esto:

- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/producing-ign/
- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/provisioning-virtualbox/

El ignition me quedó así:

```
{
  "ignition": {
    "version": "3.4.0"
  },
  "passwd": {
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "core",
        "sshAuthorizedKeys": [
          "ssh-rsa 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 jbianchini@AR0C02FM9LFML85"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Agregué la guest property a la máquina virtual, y luego habilité el ssh en el puerto 2222 para poder pegarle desde fuera, como dice la docu.

Al iniciar la vm veo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente no puedo iniciar sesión desde ese prompt, pero tengo entendido que se puede hacer ssh core@localhost -p 2222 para loguearme desde fuera usando la clave publica que agregué en el ignition.

Al hacerlo tengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PREGUNTA**

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o me está faltando? La verdad la documentación es muy pobre, dice cómo configurar el ignition file y suministrarselo a la vm pero no dice cómo hacer el login. Sólo en la parte de configuración de red dice esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias desde ya por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: `ssh user@iponombredelamaquina`  proba hace `ssh core@laipdelavm -p 2222`

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que cuando generás las claves publicas en tu local, se generan para tu usuario. Entonces en el ignition tenés que colocar

```
"users": [
    {
        "name": "nombreDeTuUsuario", --en mi caso jbianchini
        "sshAuthorizedKeys": [
            ssh-rsa la que generaste......
        ]
    }
]
```

Luego se puede hacer *ssh* usando `nombreDeTuUsuario@localhost -p 2222` y va a matchear la key con ese user.